# Invert relation in directed acyclic graph (DAG) to avoid circular relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, graph-algorithm

**Question**

In a [directed acyclic graph (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), will a circular transitive relation that would be caused by adding a relation always be prevented by inverting the relation to be added?

Example:

- Existing relations: `A -> B`, `B -> C`, and by that the transitive relation `A -> C`, so it can be viewed as `A -> B -> C`
- Relation to be added: `C -> A` which would cause `A -> B -> C -> A` and be cyclic
- **Idea**: invert the relation to be added to `C <- A` which would result in `A -> B -> C <- A` and thus still be acyclic

The example given here is of course rather simple, so I am interested to know if that approach will be viable in all scenarios.

**Background**

To model directed relations (e.g. 'follows', 'precedes', 'parent', 'child') between entities, the [OpenProject](https://community.openproject.com/projects/openproject) application stores its relation information in a [directed acyclic graph (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). The entities/nodes have date information and can be rescheduled by the user. If the user changes date values, other entities might need to be rescheduled automatically, e.g. when the predecessor is shifted two days to the future, its successor needs to be shifted as well.

Because most relations are used for scheduling and as it is an acyclic graph for that very reason, cycles are prevented. They would lead to infinite scheduling loops.

While most relations have a direction from a semantic point of view as well, there is also the generic 'relates to' relation, which to the user is undirected and simply communicates that there is a relation of sorts. Because of its nature, the direction aspect of 'relates to' relations present in the DAG is not visible to the user in the frontend.

When a user attempts to create a 'relates to' relation, he might currently run into error messages warning against cyclic relations, which is incomprehensible to the user as his perception of the relation is of being undirected.

There are a couple of possible solutions to that problem and the simplest might be to simply inverse the relation in such cases as the direction within the DAG will not matter to the user for such a relation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution seems to work. The edges `C -> A` and `A -> C` cannot both be causing a cycle.

**Proof:**

If adding `C -> A` would cause a cycle, then there already exists a path `A ↝ C`. If adding `A -> C` would cause a cycle, then there already exists a path `C ↝ A`. If both of the above were true, then combining the two paths would provide an already-existing cycle, hence the initial graph would not be a DAG.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to think about the issue @Cătălin Frâncu